# Combining 2 Flask apps using DispatcherMiddleware instance results in 404 for second app

Tags: python, flask

Sorry for ambiguous question, I'm not sure how better I can put it. So let me do the explanation of my problem.

I've the Flask application [libindic](https://github.com/libindic/Silpa-Flask/tree/development), which has 2 Flask application one is frontend and other is api. So I've wsgi.py as follows

```
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware

from silpa import api, frontend
import os

conffile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "etc", "silpa.conf")

application = DispatcherMiddleware(frontend.create_app(conffile),
                                   {'/api': api.create_app(conffile)})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_simple('0.0.0.0', 5000, application,
use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True)
```

The front end access works properly but when I hit /api/JSONRPC I get 404 error returned. This rule is defined as follows in silpa/api/jsonrpc.py

```
bp = Blueprint('api_jsonrpc', __name__, url_prefix='/api')


@route(bp, '/JSONRPC', methods=['POST'])
def handle_jsonrpc_call():
    ...
```

And when I print value of application and application.app and application.mounts in python interpreter I see folllowing

```
>>> application.app
<Flask 'silpa.frontend'>
>>> application.mounts
{'/api': <Flask 'silpa.api'>}
```

I'm unable to figure out why /api/JSONRPC results in 404. I'm not sure how can I debug it. I did check the app.url_map for api application and I can see rule for /api/JSONRPC registered there.

If some one can tell me what I might be doing wrong it would be a great help.

Comment: `@bp.route('/JSONRPC', methods=['POST'])`?

Comment: @lord63.j sorry I didn't understand what you are trying to say. bp.route is done inside the route decorator.

Comment: `@route(bp, '/JSONRPC', methods=['POST'])` this line can work?

Comment: It is supposed to work. I rechecked the decorator declaration I didn't find any problem. I'm simply lost on figuring out why app isn't working. :(

Comment: I see that you already [solved](https://github.com/libindic/Silpa-Flask/commit/e3f16d8) your problem. Would you mind answering your own question, so that others struggling with similar issues could benefit from it? It's OK to [answer your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also in commit message you state that it's unclear why original code wasn't working as expected. That was because providing URL prefix `/api` for **both** blueprint and middleware added it **two** times and  transformed URL into `/api/api/JSONRPC`.

Comment: Yeah figured it out bit later after doing that commit :-). I will write the answer myself. Sorry for delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after debugging and stepping through Flask code I figured out the reason for the problem. The following line actually caused the problem

```
bp = Blueprint('api_jsonrpc', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
```

`url_prefix` should not be present in code because I'm already mounting this app at `/api`. Adding a `/api` url_prefix will result in following url instead `/api/api/JSONRPC`. Removing the above line fixed the issue.

So if you are mouting your app at different mount point than `/` using `DispatcherMiddleware` you should not `url_prefix` in blueprint.